# how to configure jupytyer kernel in vscode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

My working path is  `~\a\b\c.ipynb` in a Ubuntu machine with vscode, and I have a python virtual environment which is in  the path: `a\.venv`, when my workspace is `a\`, this c.ipynb file can find the kernel and work, but the folder `a\` is in a mess, so i turn to use folder `b\` as my workspace, but at this time i cannot use `c.ipynb`, since it cannot find the kernel in folder `a\.venv`. When I use `select intepreter` the list did not include the path a.venv\bin\python.

So how can i configure my vscode so that i can use the ipynb file with that kernel no matter what workspace i choose?

Comment: have you tried defining a kernel.json? https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-kernel-management